# Error during plotting multiple line charts

Tags: python, pandas, plot, line

I am trying to plot a line chart with 2 lines in it (one for colA & another for colB). Dataframe looks like below:

```
date         ColA          ColB
2020-1       0.91          77
2020-2       0.88          77
2020-3       0.87          77
```

My plotting function looks like this:

```
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
fig = df.plot(x="date",y=['ColA','ColB'],kind='line')
fig.savefig("plot1.png")
```

I get the error that "date" could not be recognized

Comment: date should be of format - `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: @bigbounty: Cant that be treated as a string?  In my problem, date is in that format

Answer (score 3):

Since you are setting `date` column to be your index column, you cannot specify `date` column in plot.

Simply do this:

```
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
fig = df.plot(kind='line')
fig.savefig("plot1.png")
```